# Promlem on Adobe Air 3.6 preventBackup

Tags: ios, air

adobe air 3.6 sdk beta released with preventBackup for ios application develop .

but when i used File.preventBackup.resolvePath(dbname) it gives,

1119: Access of possibly undefined property preventBackup through a reference with static type Class.

error,

how can i make directory do not back up with preventBackup
thx.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because there is no such method or property of File class called "preventBackup"

File class is described here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#propertySummary

.resolvePath is usually used in combination with a directory property, eg:

```
File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath(dbName);
```

Edit:

According to release notes for AIR 3.6 SDK:

To use this feature, application descriptor namespace 3.6 and SWF version 19 or greater would be required

So you need this at start of application descriptor file:

```
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/3.6">
```

And this in additional compiler arguments:

```
-swf-version=19
```

Comment: thx i edit " File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup(true); " preventBackup is boolean, i give error : 1195: Attempted access of inaccessible method preventBackup through a reference with static type flash.filesystem:File.

Comment: nope there is but there is bug or something wrong in use of preventBackup .

Comment: File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup.hasOwnProperty(1); works but is it mean preventBackup is true?

Comment: please provide link to preventBackup in langauge docs - bet you cant

Comment: looks like you win! i missed fact that you're using 3.6 SDK. I have edited my answer

Comment: thx, but it didn't solve, trace(File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup) return false, when File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup.hasOwnProperty(1); i must do trace(File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup) true :(

Comment: You can only set on individual files i believe - not directories. And hasOwnProperty is used like so: File.documentsDirectory.hasOwnProperty("preventBackup")

Comment: nope adobe says, it can work with directories. http://labsdownload.adobe.com/pub/labs/flashruntimes/shared/air3-6_flashplayer11-6_releasenotes.pdf

Comment: So what error do you get when you do File.documentsDirectory.preventBackup = true. Add your code to your question